# Incorrect table definition; there can be only one auto column and it must be defined as a key

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, migration

I keep getting error while migrating in Laravel

> [PDOException]
>     SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1075 Incorrect table definition; there can be only one auto column and it must be defined
>     as a key

Code

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('inventories', function($table){

            $table->engine = 'InnoDB';

            $table->increments('id')->unsigned();
            $table->string('sku',255);
            $table->string('description', 255 )->nullable;
            $table->tinyInteger('stock',5)->nullable()->unsigned();
            $table->tinyInteger('day_of_week',1)->unsigned();
            $table->text('note')->nullable();

            $table->timestamps();

        });

    }
```

Comment: You don't have to call `unsigned()`. `increments()` does that already. However I doubt this causes the error...

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
/**
 * Create a new tiny integer column on the table.
 *
 * @param  string  $column
 * @param  bool  $autoIncrement
 * @param  bool  $unsigned
 * @return \Illuminate\Support\Fluent
 */
public function tinyInteger($column, $autoIncrement = false, $unsigned = false)
{
    return $this->addColumn('tinyInteger', $column, compact('autoIncrement', 'unsigned'));
}
```

This is the `tinyInteger()` function from `Blueprint.php`. As you can see it expects a boolean parameter here. It looks like you're trying to add a argument for size. You cannot specify the size of tinyint in Laravel.

```
    $table->engine = 'InnoDB';

    $table->increments('id');
    $table->string('sku',255);
    $table->string('description', 255 )->nullable();
    $table->tinyInteger('stock')->nullable()->unsigned();
    $table->tinyInteger('day_of_week')->unsigned();
    $table->text('note')->nullable();
```

This works fine.

Comment: Yeah so basically what happens is you pass 5 in the tinyInteger function which sees that as true and tries to auto increment that column, that's why you get the error

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
$table->integer('user_id')->length(10)->unsigned();
```

Answer (score 2):

Just to add, `$table->integer('user_id', 10)` was also throwing that error so I removed the 'size' parameter as per [Sturm](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1431389/sturm)'s answer and after taking a look at the `Blueprint` class now `migrate` works.

Comment: but i need to add size parameter, what can i do?